# Ubuntu Server joining an Active Directory Windows Domain

Tags: networking, server, mount, permissions, samba

The gist of what I want to do is add some Ubuntu Server hosts to my Windows Active Directory (2008r2 level), limit access to each server via a group, then further limit the sudo permissions on the server per a different group.

I also want to mount a cifs share as the domain users home directory, so all home directory files are stored on the Windows CIFS share and not on the server itself.

Here is the current layout of servers I have: 
5x Windows Server 2008r2 VM's 
9x Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 VM's

Of the 5 Windows Boxes here is their purpose: 
1x Windows AD Controller (2008r2 Level) 
1x Windows File Services (Hold the share for user homes) 
1x Windows Exchange 2013 Server 
2x App Servers

Now I've played with PBIS Open and it works great, Its done everything I need EXCEPT mounting the CIFS share as the user home directory. I can control all the other access permissions ect.

To be clear on the Ubuntu servers I want the home directories in /home/DOMAINNAME/remote/USER

So I'd imagine I would want to mount the CIFS share on /home/DOMAINNAME/remote however I also want the share to be unmounted when the user logs out (SSH/Console/Whatever)

I've seen posts on other websites ect where this is possible with PBIS but most refer to the enterprise side and using GPE which is not possible in the open version.

Any assistance anyone could provide would be great, if you have any questions or don't understand anything I've said I can try to clarify.

Thanks, 
DMehaffy

Comment: Might get a better response if you put the actual question as the title, rather than pointing out that there is a question - that is already assumed.